# make-kpkg build kernel with -O0 for kgdb

Tags: linux, gcc, optimization, kernel, debian

I am going to setup `kgdb` to debug `Ubuntu` `debian` kernel.

By default, the kernel compiled by `make-kpkg` has been optimized (`-O2`) so I am not able to debug the variables.

Is there a way to disable the kernel compilation optimization (for example, `-O0`)?

thanks!

Currently, gdb reports the variable has been optimized:

```
(gdb) p pb
$5 = <optimized out>
```

Comment: You will likely get the best debugging results with `-g3 -O0` or `-g3 -O1`. `-g3` includes symbolic defines. I don't know how well the kernel will perform at `-O0`. It could be painfully slow. Can you build the module of interest at  `-g3 -O0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux kernel depends on -O2.  It will not compile with any lower optimization levels.  It uses several GCC "tricks" that only work when certain optimizations are turned on, such as inline functions that are supposed to act like macros.